# How to add app icon when user swipes up? (Swift, Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I add an image to the app icon that displays when the user swipes up? This is not the same as the regular app icon (I know how to change those). The icon is blank. Below is a link to an image of what I am talking about:
[Link to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50NHu.jpg)

Comment: You need to have all of the required icon sizes in your icon set. I suggest using an icon set generator such as iconfly

Comment: @Paulw11 If "icon set" means the images with different image sizes in the assets folder, then I have already done that. I took the same image and resized it for each one.

Comment: You are missing a size otherwise it would be showing in the app switcher.

Comment: @Paulw11 I double checked and all images are in there with no warnings (all images have their correct size). Do you happen to know what the name is of the image? Is it "spotlight"?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure. I paid the $10 for iconfly and I just drop my big icon on it and it spits out the .appiconset file for me :) you won't get a warning if a size is missing.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's interesting. The way I did it was manually resizing each image (from my original, big image), making sure they all had the right size.

Comment: @Paulw11 One question: Is the ".appiconset" you mentioned the same as Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon? I do not explicitly see ".appiconset" anywhere

Comment: You can add individual icons to your asset but it is easier to use a .appiconset file in your assets. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/AppIconType.html you could try this https://appicon.co/